# If all $X_i$ are independant, can we say that $P(X_1=j|X_1+X_2=k)=P(X_1=j)$?

Tags: probability-theory

Let say that $X_1,...X_m$ are independant random variables following Poisson law of parameter λ1,...λm.

I'm searching $P(X_i=j|X_1+X_2=k)$

Can I use the fact that the $X_i$ are independant to write that

$P(X_1=j|X_1+X_2=k)=P(X_1=j)$?

Or is it forbbiden because $X_1$ and $X_1+X_2$ are not independant in this case?

Comment: $X_1$ and $X_1+X_2$ are not independent, so you can't write that.

Comment: $P(X_i=j|X_1+X_2=k)=P(X_i=j)P(X_{3-i}=k-j)/P(X_1+X_2=k)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Isn't it true that $P(X_1=3|X_1+X_2=2)=0$? But $P(X_1=3)\neq 0$.